# How To Import An MySQL While Python Only Accepts sqlite3?

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7

I am trying to use a local database over my computer using "XAMPP". The module name is MySQL & Apache. Like I was indicated by a youtube video, I had to start them two. Now, my IDLE doesn't recognize MySQL, but when I wrote sqlite3, it worked, but it had no place to take the database from. What can I do for my  program to accept MySQL?
Thanks.
My Code Looks Like This:

```
import sqlite3

print "Welcome To The Royal Bank Of The Thomean Kingdom" 
db = sqlite3.connect(host = "127.0.0.1",
                     user = "root",
                      passwd = "",
                      db="dbpython")
query = db.cursor()

loop = 'true'
while(loop == 'true'):
username = raw_input("Username:")
password = raw_input("Password:")
if(query.execute("SELECT * FROM `USERS` WHERE `username`='" + username + "' AND `password`='" + password + "'")):
    db.commit()
    print "Logged In"
else:
    db.commit()
    print "Failure"
```

Answer (score 1):

sqlite3 is a builtin Python module, which is why it works out of the box, and importing MySQL libraries will not

SQLite does not connect to MySQL or even remote/local network addresses and ports. The SQLite protocol and data formats are not even the same as MySQL.

You'll need to separately install a MySQL module, such as `mysql-python`

There's no specific reason why a local XAMPP server couldn't use SQLite and you can refer to the Python documentation for how to open / connect to a specific database file

Similarly, I see no specific reason for XAMPP here. You could use Flask or Django, and run entirely in Python, and only later add a database

---

Also, please don't write SQL queries using "string + string" - it allows for *SQL injection* attacks. The solution is to use *prepared statements*

Also, storing passwords directly in your database immediately after user entry (i.e in plain text) is just asking for trouble